# Holding shift to disable autorun programs doesn't work?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, boot, reboot

I'm running windows XP SP3. I read that if you hold down Shift while starting up windows it should disable startup programs but it does not. What's going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> disables the [AutoPlay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoPlay) function when you insert a disc or removable media. It does not apply to Windows' login/startup. If you are looking to disable or remove startup entries, you can use [MSConfig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSConfig) or a utility such as [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902).

Comment: I see.... got it.

Comment: I've updated my answer to point you in the correct direction. :)

Comment: The shift command [does work](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/AutoPlay-frequently-asked-questions) on versions earlier than Vista. In windows XP it caused it to not run the AutoRun program defined in `autorun.inf`, in Vista it caused the AutoPlay dialog to be shown.